# How to connect javascript var with text?

Tags: javascript

How to connect javascript var `xx` with `/\` and `\b/` ?

https://jsfiddle.net/6r4o5278/6/

```
<div onclick="check()">CLICK HERE</div>

<script>
  function check() {
    var str = "abcdefg";
    var xx = "abc";
    if (/\+xx+\b/.test(str)) 
    {
      alert("found");
    } else 
    {
      alert("not found");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your regex before testing.

```
....
var xx = /abc\b/;
if (xx.test(str)) {
...
```

Note that this will not match the string "abcdefg" because `\b` is a Word Boundary flag.

Comment: i have to use  `/\abc\b/`

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'connect javascript var xx with /\ and \b/'. Furthermore see:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp

```
// The string:
var str = "Hello world!";

// Look for "Hello"
var patt = /Hello/g;
var result = patt.test(str);

// Look for "W3Schools"
patt2 = /W3Schools/g;
result2 = patt2.test(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one surely work...:)

```
var test = '/\\' + xx + '\\b/';
console.log(test);
```

it will be /\abc\b/.

Answer (score 0):

Try to construct the expression this way:

```html
<script>
  function check(value) {
    var str = "abcdefg";
    var re = new RegExp(value);
    var found = str.match(re);
    if (found) {
      console.log(value + " - found");
    }
    else
    { 
      console.log(value + " - not found");
    }
  }
  check('xsxsd');
  check('abc');
  check('refer');
  check('cde');
</script>
```